# Is Star Wars prequel trilogy inspired by Augustus and Roman politics of his time?

Tags: star-wars

Star Wars prequel trilogy introduced The Galactic Republic and to make it compatible with the original trilogy, Lucas showed how Galactic Empire was established replacing The Galactic Republic.

This thing looks similar to how Roman Empire replaced Roman Republic in 27 BC. Did Lucas ever told that he was inspired by the same?

Comment: @KaiQing - but could the same be said of the Roman republic to empire transition? :-)

Comment: I believe George Lucas has mentioned that though there are quite a lot of similarities to George W. Bush's presidency (including the line “If you’re not with me then you’re my enemy”, he intended it to be a reflection on Nixon's presidency. See more here: https://www.huffingtonpost.com/entry/star-wars-is-more-political-than-you-think_us_590b663de4b056aa2363d298 and here: http://articles.chicagotribune.com/2005-05-18/features/0505180309_1_star-wars-sith-palpatine and here: http://poliscijedi.blogspot.com/2014/04/nixon-in-star-wars.html